# How does an object pass itself as a parameter?

Tags: java, parameters

I have a JFrame that is the main class of the program. I want to pass him itself to another two classes, one that will update some label with statistics and another that will validate a lot of fields.

I done the getters to these fields, but how I do to the JFrame pass itself to these classes to they can do their work?

**EDIT:** My error, my fault. The first thing I done is the `this` method. Yes, `this` solves my problem, but it did not realize that I was making a mistake.

I was doing this: `new Statistics().execute(this);`
where the right thing is this: `new Statistics(this).execute();`

Only with all the answers saying the same thing I realized that I was doing a stupid thing.
Thanks to all.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Because if you want to pass himself, you need to modify some method of JFrame and insert this 'passing' to this method. What do you mean by passing JFram itself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just pass a reference to `this`

```
public class Other {

   public void doSomething(JFrame jFrame) {
      ...
   }
} 

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

   Other other = new Other();

   public void method() {
      other.doSomething(this);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The pseudo-variable `this` always points to the current object in an instance method. Just pass `this` as the argument where you want the reference to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this` to pass itself within a method.

```
foo(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try using `this` ?

For example:

```
other.doSomething(this)
```